# Rabbit MQ upgrade from 3.6.x to 3.8.x version in Windows

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmqctl

I have installed RabbitMQ 3.6 version and Erlang 19.x version on my windows system. Now I need to upgrade the versions of rabbitmq to the latest version 3.8.x. I have checked the upgrade documentation and not clear for windows. Any reference doc (steps for upgrade) available for upgrade this version?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ 3.8.x requires Erlang 22.x

You can have a look at this document https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Comment: I need to update both RabbitMQ and erlang.